# Koajs yield the function return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

In expressjs, I usually use asynchronous function like below:

```
function foo(callback) {
  var bar = {a: 1, b: 2};
  callback(null, bar);
}

foo(function(err, result) {
  // result is {a: 1, b: 2}
});
```

In Koajs, I use the `yield` in route function like below:

```
function foo(callback) {
  var bar = {a: 1, b: 2};
  callback(null, bar);
}
var result = yield foo.bind(null); // [{a: 1, b: 2}]
```

I expect the result is `{a: 1, b: 2}`, but the result is a array `[{a: 1, b: 2}]` in fact.

So, how can I get the expect value in koajs?

Comment: To be honest, I'm a little surprised this works at all, since you can't typically yield regular functions with [co](https://github.com/tj/co#yieldables). Koajs must be doing some sort of manipulation which allows you to yield regular functions. Either way, I'm not actually seeing the array you're seeing. What version of koa are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Koa vs Co shenanigans aside, you should really promisify your async methods, preferably by modifying the original functions (if that's a possibility for you):

```
function foo() {
    let bar = { a: 1, b: 2 };
    return Promise.resolve(bar);
}

let data = yield foo();
```

If that's *not* a possibility (too many functions to convert, still being used as callbacks elsewhere, using someone else's functions, etc), you may wrap them like this:

```
function fooPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // assume foo is defined externally
        foo((err, result) => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            return resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

let data = yield fooPromise();
```

There are some libraries which will wrap callback methods for you, such as [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html), but it's pretty straightforward to do yourself if there are just a few to cover.